# perl glob check if file with prefix exists

Tags: perl, glob

I get some strange behaviour searching for files using `glob`.
(I think its intended, but I don't want it in my case)

I have 2 files named `aaa:bbb` and `aaa:ccc`.

I have code to see if files with prefix `aaa:*` exists. I do this with this code:

```
my $filelocation_special = "aaa";

if (glob($filelocation_special . ":*")) {
  # file(s) exists!
}
```

This works. However, if I run the same code again two more times glob returns undefined.

these are my returns: (most of the time anyway)

```
print STDERR "glob: " . glob($filelocation_special . ":*") . "\n";

# 1 run: aaa:bbb
# 2 run: aaa:ccc
# 3 run:
```

What can I do to *reset* `glob`to always just check if files with this prefix exists?

Maybe I should use some different check altogether, but I can't seem to find anything that is fast and just checks if the files exists.

Comment: It this `CORE::glob` or `:bsd_glob` from http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html?

Comment: The requests come from our iOS app. So there is some delay between the code that runs. To run it 3 times takes around 5 seconds.

Comment: Assigning the result of `glob` to an array will fix this, and it's highly likely that you'll want to know the names of the files as well as just whether they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (glob(...))` is a [call to `glob` in scalar context](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#glob).

> In scalar context, glob iterates through
>   such filename expansions, returning undef when the list is
>   exhausted.

So everytime you call `glob` in scalar context, with the same arguments, and *from the same line of code*, you will get a different result, and eventually you will get `undef` when the list of files that match your argument are exhausted.

To get your expression to mean "if there are files that match this pattern ...", you need to use list context somehow.

```
@tmp = glob(pattern)
if (@tmp) 

if (()=glob(pattern))

if (@{[glob(pattern)]})
```

---

Diversion: any of these also work (because `@*` are valid global array identifiers for many values of punctuation character `*`)

```
if (@@=glob(pattern))
if (@<=glob(pattern))
if (@:=glob(pattern))
```

and they can even be written like

```
if (@ <= glob(pattern))
if (@ := glob(pattern))
```

and so a few more candidates for [secret operators](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsecret) are suggested.

```
@@ = EXPR       like the goatse operator, returns a count of elements
@ <= EXPR       in EXPR when EXPR is evaluated in list context; useful
@ := EXPR       when EXPR in scalar context does not do this
```

Comment: Wow. That is some really wierd code. I tried it though. And it worked just the way I wanted it to. Thanks!

Comment: There's some good discussion on scalar glob at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633447/why-doesnt-perl-file-glob-work-outside-of-a-loop-in-scalar-context).

Comment: Using symbolic identifiers like that is discouraged because they are reserved for Perl built-in variables. It is also highly inconsiderate to write code using undefined symbolic variables with spaces in unusual places, as most Perl programmers will be unable to parse it quickly. The obvious way to check the existence of files matching a `glob` pattern is with `if ( my @files = glob 'aaa:*' ) { ... }` where the array `@files` is defined only for the length of the `if` block. "secret operators" are mostly infantile toys rather than valid constructs for use in production software